# Twitter4j get followers who have most follower count

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

Im using twitter 4j for an small twitter application and im currently using the following code to get the followers ids, what i need is for an user(let says ME) i like to have top 10 user who have most followers count( the following code gets profileIDs of an user). in my twitter profile i got 80 followers and i like to fetch followers who have more followers(first 10)

```
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
twitter.setOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_KEY_SECRET);
String accessToken = getSavedAccessToken();
String accessTokenSecret = getSavedAccessTokenSecret();
AccessToken oathAccessToken = new AccessToken(accessToken, accessTokenSecret);

twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(oathAccessToken);
User user = null;
try {
    user = twitter.showUser(username);// id = user.getId();
} catch (TwitterException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To retrieve followers of a given user using their screen name, see [`Twitter#getFollowersList()`](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/api/FriendsFollowersResources.html#getFollowersList%28java.lang.String,%20long%29), for example:

```
long cursor = -1;
PagableResponseList<User> followers;
do {
     followers = twitter.getFollowersList("screenName", cursor);
    for (User follower : followers) {
        // TODO: Collect top 10 followers here
        System.out.println(follower.getName() + " has " + follower.getFollowersCount() + " follower(s)");
    }
} while ((cursor = followers.getNextCursor()) != 0);
```

I've used a cursor to retrieve all the followers, by default the api call only returns twenty - see Twitter's guide on [Using cursors to navigate](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/misc/cursoring) for more information.

Within the for-loop you can collect your 'top 10' followers by inspecting the followers count.

Comment: thx for the reply and i have tried if condition inside for loop to check if the followerscount is more than 1000 then print name and id but since the PagableResponseList fetches 20 at a time i cant get my top 10 followers who have more followers to them selves, please advise me if im wrong.

Comment: No problem. How about storing the followers you retrieve in a list and then sorting them by `followersCount`? That should yield which of your followers have the most followers.

Comment: thanks for your reply and by your suggestion i tried to create an array with length of the user follower count( billgates - 13,554,291
FOLLOWERS) and tried to get just the followers ids and tried to store the ids in the array 
first i got java heap memory error but increased the memory but now getting rate limit error :( `429:Returned in API v1.1 when a request cannot be served due to the application's rate limit having been exhausted for the resource. See Rate Limiting in API v1.1.(https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1)
message - Rate limit exceeded
code - 88 `